# golang fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock upon implementing Lamport Logical Clock

Tags: go

I am implementing a set of codes that prints Lamport logical time upon the completion of sending messages to servers and broadcasting to nodes. My program runs fine before I implemented the codes Lamport logical time. Upon printing  `closing server...`, the program breaks and shows deadlock. May I know if anyone can help me spot my mistake?

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "time"
)

const num_nodes int = 3
const num_messages int = 2

// some arbitary large number
const buffer_channel = 10000

type Server struct {
    serverChannel chan Message
    nodeArray     []Node
    timestamp     int
}

type Node struct {
    nodeId       int
    nodeChannel  chan Message
    server       Server
    closeChannel chan int
    readyChannel chan int
    timestamp    int
}

type Message struct {
    senderId  int
    messageId int
    timestamp int
}

func max(x int, y int) int {
    if x > y {
        return x
    }
    return y
}

func broadcast(m Message, s Server) {
    for _, n := range s.nodeArray {
        if n.nodeId != m.senderId {
            broadcastMessage := Message{
                m.senderId,
                m.messageId,
                s.timestamp,
            }
            go s.broadcastMessage(n.nodeChannel, broadcastMessage)
        }
    }
}

func (s Server) broadcastMessage(nodeChannel chan Message, broadcastMessage Message) {
    fmt.Printf("[Server] is sending Message %d.%d to [Node %d]\n", broadcastMessage.senderId, broadcastMessage.messageId, broadcastMessage.senderId)
    nodeChannel <- broadcastMessage
}

func (s Server) listen(messagesBufferChannel chan Message) {
    numCompletedNodes := 0

    for {
        nodeMessage := <-s.serverChannel
        s.timestamp = max(s.timestamp, nodeMessage.timestamp) + 1
        nodeMessage.timestamp = s.timestamp
        fmt.Printf("TS: %d -- [Server] has received Message %d.%d from [Node %d]\n", s.timestamp, nodeMessage.senderId, nodeMessage.messageId, nodeMessage.senderId)
        messagesBufferChannel <- nodeMessage

        s.timestamp += 1
        broadcast(nodeMessage, s)

        if nodeMessage.messageId == num_messages-1 {
            numCompletedNodes += 1
            if numCompletedNodes == num_nodes {
                fmt.Println("Server finish broadcasting all messages. Stopping Server...")
                return
            }
        }

        numMilliSeconds := rand.Intn(1000) + 2000
        time.Sleep(time.Duration(numMilliSeconds) * time.Millisecond)
    }
}

func (n Node) preSendMessage() {
    for i := 1; i <= num_messages; i++ {
        numMilliSeconds := rand.Intn(1000) + 2000
        time.Sleep(time.Duration(numMilliSeconds) * time.Millisecond)
        n.readyChannel <- i
    }
}

func (n Node) listenSendMessages(messagesBufferChannel chan Message) {
    for {
        select {
        case receivedMessage := <-n.nodeChannel:
            n.timestamp = max(n.timestamp, receivedMessage.timestamp) + 1
            receivedMessage.timestamp = n.timestamp
            fmt.Printf("TS: %d -- [Node %d] has received Message %d.%d from [Server]\n", n.timestamp, n.nodeId, receivedMessage.senderId, receivedMessage.messageId)
            messagesBufferChannel <- receivedMessage

        case nodeMessageId := <-n.readyChannel:
            n.timestamp += 1
            fmt.Printf("TS: %d -- [Node %d] is sending Message %d.%d to [Server]\n", n.timestamp, n.nodeId, n.nodeId, nodeMessageId)
            nodeMessage := Message{
                n.nodeId,
                nodeMessageId,
                n.timestamp,
            }
            n.server.serverChannel <- nodeMessage

        case <-n.closeChannel:
            fmt.Printf("Stopping [node %d]\n", n.nodeId)
            return
        default:
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Start of Program...")

    server := Server{
        serverChannel: make(chan Message),
        nodeArray:     []Node{},
        timestamp:     0,
    }

    for i := 1; i <= num_nodes; i++ {
        newNode := Node{
            nodeId:       i,
            nodeChannel:  make(chan Message),
            server:       server,
            readyChannel: make(chan int),
            closeChannel: make(chan int),
            timestamp:    0,
        }
        server.nodeArray = append(server.nodeArray, newNode)
    }

    var messagesBufferChannel chan Message = make(chan Message, buffer_channel)

    for _, n := range server.nodeArray {
        go n.preSendMessage()
        go n.listenSendMessages(messagesBufferChannel)
    }

    server.listen(messagesBufferChannel)

    time.Sleep(time.Second)
    for _, n := range server.nodeArray {
        n.closeChannel <- 1
    }
    time.Sleep(time.Second)

    close(messagesBufferChannel)

}
```

Comment: @LinPy how can I do so? I have tried to use waitsync, but my implementation still causes me to enter deadlock. Are you able to provide me a snippet of codes for that portion?